# Python multithreading doesn't increase speed

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, threadpool

I have 2 separate files that contain the coordinates of a place and the other containing the street and postal code.

By using `pandas` I want to create a new Dataframe that contains all three parameters by by mapping them with a unique key. The problem is that it takes too long.

This is the code to mapping them by unique key:

```
def group_comp_with_coord(comp_coord):
    comp_dict = comp_coord[1].to_dict()
    index = comp_coord[0]
    comp_dict.pop('Unnamed: 0', None)
    if index % 10000 == 0:
        print(index)
    comp = companies[(companies.uen == comp_dict['uen'])]
    comp_dict['reg_street_name'] = comp['reg_street_name'].item()
    comp_dict['reg_postal_code'] = comp['reg_postal_code'].item()
    return comp_dict
```

This is the multi-threading code:

```
s = time.time()
test = companies_coordinates.head(100)
pool = ThredPool(5)
company_items = pool.map(group_comp_with_coord, test.iterrows())
pool.close()
pool.join()
df = pd.DataFrame(company_items)
df.to_csv('singapore_companies_coordinates_v2.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
print('Passed', time.time() - s)
```

The problem here is that even if it doesn't matter how many threads I'm giving to `ThreadPool` it always creates the file in 6 seconds with 100 rows of data.

How can I increase the speed?

Comment: Are you sure the 6 seconds are spent in the mapping and not in the call `to_csv()`?

Comment: yes, tested again, same result.

Comment: Can you run a line per line profiler and comes back to us after? I cannot test as I dont have the data (Tag me when its done plz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python uses GIL ([global interpreter lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)), it prevents multiple threads from executing Python bytecodes at once. In other words, only one thread is executed at once, so it is almost impossible to achieve any significant performance boost in your case.

You should try to use Python [Multiprocessing Pool](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) instead, which is not limited by GIL:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

...
pool = Pool(5)
company_items = pool.map(group_comp_with_coord, test.iterrows())
...
```

Comment: However, IO-bound workloads, or those executed mostly in native code (i.e. C extensions, numpy, ...) usually are accelerated by threads.

Comment: @AKX Yes, but C extensions and partially numpy (half of it is in a plain C) use native C code/threads, not Python interpreter, so GIL is not involved there. This is one of the most trickiest parts in Python, that threads may be useful, but not in a sake of performance.

Comment: Point being that if you spawn Python threads and "drop into" C code in them, the C code will run in parallel (if it's written correctly to release the GIL) with Python code in other threads.